# Different behavior between ggplot2 and plotly using ggplotly

Tags: r, ggplot2, plotly

I want to make a line chart in `plotly` so that it does not have the same color on its whole length. The color is given continuous scale. It is easy in `ggplot2` but when I translate it to `plotly` using `ggplotly` function the variable determining color behaves like categorical variable.

```
require(dplyr)
require(ggplot2)
require(plotly)

df <- data_frame(
  x = 1:15,
  group = rep(c(1,2,1), each = 5),
  y = 1:15 + group
)

gg <- ggplot(df) +
  aes(x, y, col = group) +
  geom_line()

gg           # ggplot2
ggplotly(gg) # plotly
```

**ggplot2** (desired):
[image]
**plotly**:
[image]

I found one work-around that, on the other hand, behaves oddly in `ggplot2`.

```
df2 <- df %>% 
  tidyr::crossing(col = unique(.$group)) %>% 
  mutate(y = ifelse(group == col, y, NA)) %>% 
  arrange(col)

gg2 <- ggplot(df2) +
  aes(x, y, col = col) +
  geom_line()

gg2
ggplotly(gg2)
```

I also did not find a way how to do this in plotly directly. Maybe there is no solution at all. Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like ggplotly is treating `group` as a factor, even though it's numeric. You could use `geom_segment` as a workaround to ensure that segments are drawn between each pair of points:

```
gg2 = ggplot(df, aes(x,y,colour=group)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=lead(x), y=y, yend=lead(y)))

gg2
```

[image]

```
ggplotly(gg2)
```

[image]

Regarding @rawr's (now deleted) comment, I think it would make sense to have `group` be continuous if you want to map line color to a continuous variable. Below is an extension of the OP's example to a `group` column that's continuous, rather than having just two discrete categories.

```
set.seed(49)
df3 <- data_frame(
  x = 1:50,
  group = cumsum(rnorm(50)),
  y = 1:50 + group
)
```

Plot `gg3` below uses `geom_line`, but I've also included `geom_point`. You can see that `ggplotly` is plotting the points. However, there are no lines, because no two points have the same value of `group`. If we hadn't included `geom_point`, the graph would be blank.

```
gg3 <- ggplot(df3, aes(x, y, colour = group)) +
  geom_point() + geom_line() +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low="red",mid="yellow",high="blue")

gg3
```

[image]

```
ggplotly(gg3)
```

[image]

Switching to `geom_segment` gives us the lines we want with `ggplotly`. Note, however, that line color will be based on the value of `group` at the first point in the segment (whether using `geom_line` or `geom_segment`), so there might be cases where you want to interpolate the value of `group` between each (x,y) pair in order to get smoother color gradations:

```
gg4 <- ggplot(df3, aes(x, y, colour = group)) +
  geom_segment(aes(x=x, xend=lead(x), y=y, yend=lead(y))) +
  scale_colour_gradient2(low="red",mid="yellow",high="blue")

ggplotly(gg4)
```

[image]